# Por que nil si ya se cargo el valor?

Tags: ios, swift, popup, uitableview, uitableviewcell

La es un tableview que al dar click en un celda va a un popup y carga la informacion de la celda, todo bien hasta que tengo que cargar la informacion que traego de la API ya se carga en la pantalla principal pero cuando le doy click en la celda, crashea y dice que todo es nil

1.-Aqui esta el model que carga los datos en el tableview
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2.-Este el viewController del popup donde quiero cargar los datos de la celda del tableview
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3.- Aqui el codigo del tableview y del metodo didselectedrow para que dispare el segue y cargue los datos en el popup
pero me tira nil :(

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

4.- El error,no entiendo si el valor ya se cargo en el viewcontroller o el tableview por que me tira nil

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

asi luce el table View

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código va como texto no como imagen.

Comment: Estás creando un objeto MovieCell() el cual está vacío y luego haces unwrap de un valor nulo, por eso el error. Cómo asignas los valores al momento de crear el objeto?

Comment: los valores los asigno en el model de la primera imagen, ahi se crean con la funcion configure, y en el cesllforrow cargo la funcion poblando la tabla, pero lo que no entiendo es como puedo pasar los valores por ejemplo de la primera imagen o de la table view al otro view por el segue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como te puse en el comentario, estás creando un Objeto nuevo en esta línea:

```
let data = MovieCell()
```

Lo que debes hacer es enviar el valor de la celda que seleccionas en esta función:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! MovieCell
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "popUp", sender: cell)//Envías cell no self
}
```

Y al hacer el `segue` utilizas el valor de la celda que envías en el `sender`:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "popUp" {
        if let cell = sender as? MovieCell {//Aquí conviertes el sender en MovieCell
            let destinationVC = segue.destination as! popUpViewController
            //Ya puedes obtener el valor de la celda seleccionada y asignar 
            destinationVC.movieN = cell.title.text
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Toda la razon ahora si funciono

Comment: Muchas gracias Bicho!! buen dia